# Squirrel Client Connecting to Phoenix - Timeout Exception

Tags: jdbc, timeout, hbase, squirrel-sql, apache-phoenix

I am trying to connect to Phoenix via Squirrel client. I am receiving the following logs in the Squirrel logs. The logs suggests that the ClientConnection to zooperkeeper is established however it fails when a SQLClient Connection is being established with a Timeout exception.

I have copied the phoenix client jar into the lib directory of Squirrel and the driver is registered succesfully. Also when I run the SQLLine.py utility in the localhost it loads the SQL commandline to Phoenix succesfully and I can run the commands. Added the phoenix core jars to the $HBASE_HOME/lib folders as well.

```
2015-06-15 12:48:53,766 [pool-7-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper  - Process identifier=hconnection-0x776a1002 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=10.58.126.245:2181
2015-06-15 12:48:53,766 [pool-7-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Initiating client connection, connectString=10.58.126.245:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x776a10020x0, quorum=10.58.126.245:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2015-06-15 12:48:58,287 [pool-7-thread-1-SendThread(10.58.126.245:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to server 10.58.126.245/10.58.126.245:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-06-15 12:48:58,301 [pool-7-thread-1-SendThread(10.58.126.245:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to 10.58.126.245/10.58.126.245:2181, initiating session
2015-06-15 12:48:58,314 [pool-7-thread-1-SendThread(10.58.126.245:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session establishment complete on server 10.58.126.245/10.58.126.245:2181, sessionid = 0x14df5b87b120040, negotiated timeout = 90000
2015-06-15 12:49:58,100 [pool-7-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller  - Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=59774 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
2015-06-15 12:50:20,456 [pool-7-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller  - Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=82130 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
2015-06-15 12:50:36,114 [AWT-EventQueue-1] ERROR net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.db.ConnectToAliasCallBack  - Unexpected Error occurred attempting to open an SQL connection.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.awaitConnection(OpenConnectionCommand.java:132)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$100(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$2.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, don't find the solution yet, but I managed to use the "thin" client instead.

1. Start queryserver https://phoenix.apache.org/server.html should listen on port 8765
2. Copy JAR phoenix-4.6.0-HBase-1.1-thin-client to Squirel lib folder
3. Create new driver, the class name is "org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.client.Driver"
4. Connect with this driver (my URI: jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://docker:8765)

Comment: what is difference between phoenix-4.6.0-HBase-1.1-thin-client and phoenix-4.6.0-HBase-1.1-client ?

Comment: thin client uses a custom API between server and client (that I found easier to get it working).

Comment: Do you have any references for api documentation ?

Comment: This is what i am getting with this solution **java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.phoenix.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('o' (code 111)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: 
8org.apache.calcite.avatica.proto.Responses$ErrorResponse**